# How to puts html elements inside of the template literal expression

Tags: javascript, string, template-literals, htmlelements

```js
let word = "kemal"

let test = document.createElement("div");
test.innerText = `lorem la la bla bla "${<strong>word</strong>}"`;
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(test);
```

I want to make bold font to word variable. But I got an error about it. How can I use HTML elements inside of the template literal?

Comment: um: `\`lorem la la bla bla "<strong>${word}</strong>"\`` but innerText is not going to output html.

Comment: **Template Literal** expressions are expected to be javascript expressions that can be evaluated.  "<html>stuff<html>" is not a javascript expression

Comment: Side note; adding markup to the element with `innerText` is most likely going to not be what you want.  You want to use `innerHTML` if you want the markup to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use innerHTML instead of innerText.

```
test.innerHTML = "lorem la la bla bla <strong>word</strong>";
```

Example:

```
let test = document.createElement("div");
test.innerHTML = "lorem la la bla bla <strong>word</strong>";
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(test);
```

if you want to replace `word` with a variable:

```
test.innerHTML = `lorem la la bla bla <strong>${word}</strong>`;
```

Example:

```
let word = "Some Word";
let test = document.createElement("div");
test.innerHTML = `lorem la la bla bla <strong>${word}</strong>`;
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(test);
```

Comment: This is not working bro. This implementation gives result like this "lorem la la bla bla <strong>the-word-value</strong>"